# How to debug chrome manifest.json?

Tags: google-chrome, manifest, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on a chrome.bluetooth app. However, there's something wrong with the manifest.json. However, I don't see any way to set a breakpoint in the manifest.json - obviously, it's declarative.

My manifest.json is:

```
{
  "name": "Bluetooth Low Energy Test App",
  "description": "App testing the chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy API",
  "version": "0.1",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "bluetooth": {
    "low_energy": true
  }
}
```

Is there a way to debug manifest.json? That is, to see how or where it may be providing the wrong values for it's various declarations. A linter? Anything?

I've tried this on stable (42) and canary (44) builds of chrome on Mac OSX and ChromeOS and don't see an obvious solution.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, I know, but for future reference. Check out this page on Chrome Dev Tools about debugging PWAs. It says that in the Application tab of the dev tools, you can choose the "Manifest" option.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/progressive-web-apps#manifest

Comment: have you actually tried this though? I don't see the manifest.json on a per extension basis

Answer (score 0):

Debug manifest.json? easy! you just need to edit the manifest.json, if you can't open manifest.json, open it with a notepad, or any text editor, if you want to debug a manifest.json from a chrome extension that is not loaded from local storage, then go to chrome extension's root folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).